# Angular push values from an array into another array of chart label

Tags: arrays, angular, charts, label

I'm trying to push values into my chart label array but it wont display on the chart after doing so. Am i doing something wrong? Here's the code.

```
public barChartLabels: Label[] = [];

this.mailboxTags.getTotalPending().subscribe((tags: Tag[]) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < tags.length; index++) {
    if(tags[index].type == 'category')
    {
      this.barChartLabels.push(tags[index].name);
    } 
  }
});
```

So if i console log the barchartlabels after pushing in the values i get these,

```
0: "general"
1: "Software"
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

which is the correct data but it doesnt show up on the bar chart as label. If i just hardcode

```
public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['general', 'software'];
```

then it works. What am i doing wrong here? I even tried the

```
this.barChartLabels.push(tags[index].name.toString());
```

but it still doesnt work.
Edit: Just found this later on that this works, it's just that the changes dont reflect immediately after page load. I need to click something to make the changes appear.

Comment: How is `barChartLabels` being referenced in your template?

Comment: <div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart
    [datasets]="barChartData"
    [labels]="barChartLabels"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
    [legend]="barChartLegend"
    [chartType]="barChartType">
  </canvas>
</div> Later on i found that it works but it doesnt load the changes on pageload. I need to click something then the graph will update. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be to do with how Angular's change detection works. When Angular checks if the view needs updating, it checks if the expression values in the template have changed.

In this case `barChartLabels` has been mutated but the reference is the same. Angular doesn't check for changes in an object and so the view is not updated.

One way to fix this is by assigning `barChartLabels` in `subscribe`.

```
this.mailboxTags.getTotalPending().subscribe((tags: Tag[]) => {
  const categoryTagNames = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < tags.length; index++) {
    if(tags[index].type == 'category')
    {
      categoryTags.push(tags[index].name);
    } 
  }
  this.barChartLabels = categoryTagNames;
});
```